# Is the sentence natural in passive?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence natural in passive? If not, please explain  to me what the reason is.

> Some of the dreams can be controlled by certain people.

Comment: It sounds natural to me (non-native English speaker).

Comment: It sounds grammatical, though somewhat impossible if read literally.  What is the context of this sentence (that is, are the dreams literal or metaphorical) and what do you think it should mean?

Comment: @ Canadian Yankee, the dreams are literal, not metaphorical. The sentence means that certain people make sure the dreams have a happy ending. They can get relief from bad dreams.

Comment: What is the active version of this sentence that you are trying to make passive?

Comment: @ Andrew, Certain people can control some of their dreams.

Comment: @theinlwin If you mean that some people can control their own dreams, then that's not obvious at all from your sentence. I said it "sounded impossible" because it reads like you are saying that there are some people who can control **other people's** dreams.

Answer (score 1):

You've said that the active version of the sentence is this:

> Certain people can control some of their dreams.

Your passive construction does not mean the same thing, because the active has the possessive **their**, which clearly associates the dreams as belonging to the person dreaming (and controlling) them.  On the other hand, you have constructed this passive sentence:

> Some of the dreams can be controlled by certain people.

You have lost that possessive connection.  It sounds like certain people can control some dreams, even if they're being dreamt by *other people*, which sounds like science fiction or magic.

Here is a formation that restores that possessive:

> Some dreams can be controlled by their dreamers.

Note that I have not only restored a possessive, but I also deleted the "of the" out of "some of the dreams."  In general, the passive form of this sentence is always going to be inferior to the active form because, by putting "some [of the] dreams" at the beginning of the sentence, you're implying that the type or content of the dream is the deciding factor as to whether it can be controlled.  This is even more the case if you have the phrase "some of the dreams," which really emphasizes that you're choosing some dreams (e.g., all dreams about dead relatives) and saying that those are the ones that any dreamer can control.

If you're emphasizing that some people are [lucid dreamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream) and can control their dreams, then you should *always* use the active construction and put "certain people" or "some people" at the start of the sentence.

As an analogy, compare these two sentences:

> 1. Some dog-owners can easily train their dogs.
> 2. Some dogs are easily trained by their owners.

Even though it looks like these two sentences are just active/passive versions of the same basic sentence, they have distinctly different meanings, because of which noun gets the "some" qualifier at the beginning of the sentence.  Sentence 1 means that there are some dog owners who are very good at training their dogs.  Sentence 2 means that there are some dogs that respond very well to training. Your choice of which construction to use in this case depends on whether you want to emphasize the teaching skill of the owner (#1) or the learning ability of the dog (#2).

With your example, you get a similar change in emphasis and meaning of the sentence when shifting between active and passive.